# Spans of linearly independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

> "Find a linearly independent set of vectors that spans the same subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ as that spanned by the vectors (in that order)
>   $\begin{pmatrix}-2\\ -1\\ -2\end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix}-2\\ -2\\ 1\end{pmatrix} $, and $\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ -3\end{pmatrix}$."

The answer should have $2$ vectors rather than the initial $3$. I know that when linearly independent vectors are combined together to form a matrix, they have a non-zero determinant. So am I supposed to find a combination of any two vectors into a matrix that have a non-zero determinant or is it something more specific?

Any help?

Comment: Can't you simply use the first two vectors, which are linearly independent?

Comment: Yes. I see that you are correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

from top to bottom, these are vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$. Note that $v_3=v_1-v_2$, so you can simply ignore the third.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

- If you have two vectors of $\mathbb{R}^3$, we can't talk about determinant as it is not a square matrix.
- When it comes to two vectors, they are linearly dependent if they are not multiple of each other.
- To improve your understanding, try to drop each vector and ask yourself if they still span the same space.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you're looking for a base of a subspace $S$, where $S = gen\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$. And those vectors are the ones you just listed

Now, what you need to do is try find the solutions to the equation $av_1 + bv_2 + cv_3 = 0$ where $0$ is the null vector and a,b,c are real constants.

This system of equations can be converted into a 3x3 matrix $A$, where $A = (v_1|v_2|v_3)$ (that is, the vectors are A's columns). This is "actually an augmented matrix" but we ignore the last column because they're all zeros so no matrix operation will affect it.

So now all that's left is bring it to a reduced echelon form (I think it's called like that). If A's reduced echelon form is a 3x3 by identity, then your 3 vectors are linearly independent and what you had was already base. If it's not, that means that at least one of them was a linear combination of the others. To know which one to exclude, you use A's reduced echelon form to find out which vector is a linear combination of the others (the columns with 1's will be LI, all other columns will show you the linear combination of the other vectors that add up to the vector corresponding to your column).

Edit: since I don't know the actual name, reduced echelon form means operating on your rows to achieve an equivalent matrix in which the first element of each row is a 1 (called a "principal one"), and every element below and above the principal 1's are all zeroes